# Python: Rolling dice again when at max randint value

Tags: python, random, dice

I'm working on a small project to help some of my players that I GM for. Essentially, I want to create an automated system that will roll dice in the OpenLegend RPG system using its rules.

One element of the system is a "dice explosion." If you roll the maximum value on a dice, you roll it again, adding the previous value and the new one as well, continuing as many times as it "explodes". I'm having some difficulty figuring out how I would do this, however. At present, my code looks like this:

```
from random import randint as ri

def action_roll_script(attribute, score):

d20 = ri(1, 20)

if score == 0:
    roll = d20
if score == 1:
    roll = ri(1,4)
if score == 2:
    roll = ri(1,6)
if score == 3:
    roll = ri(1,8)
if score == 4:
    roll = ri(1,10)
if score == 5:
    roll = ri(1,6) + ri(1,6)
if score == 6:
    roll = ri(1,8) + ri(1,8)
if score == 7:
    roll = ri(1,10) + ri(1,10)
if score == 8:
    roll = ri(1, 8) + ri(1, 8) + ri(1, 8)
if score == 9:
    roll = ri(1, 10) + ri(1, 10) + ri(1, 10)
if score == 10:
    roll = ri(1, 8) + ri(1, 10) + ri(1, 10) + ri(1, 10)

print(d20)
print(roll)

outcome = str(roll + d20)

print("You got a " + attribute + " roll of " + outcome + "!")
```

Now, obviously that's fairly inefficient with entirely too many if statements. I'll work on using a dictionary/list for that later. My question for you all is: how can I tell the script to roll the dice again when it lands on a maximum value? For example, if it rolls a 20 on a d20, I want it to save the previous result and roll again, continuing as many times as it gets a 20.

Answer (score 0):

Try using recursion:

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
from random import randint as ri
MAX_DICE_NUMBER = 20
def roll_dice():
    attempt = ri(1, MAX_DICE_NUMBER)
    if attempt == MAX_DICE_NUMBER:
        return attempt + roll_dice()
    else:
        return attempt

def action_roll_script(attribute):
    print("You got a " + attribute + " roll of " + str(roll_dice()) + "!")

action_roll_script('power')
>>> You got a power roll of 16!
```

I didn't understand why you needed score though...

But this piece still might be useful :)

Comment: Thank you so much! "Score" refers to the relevant attribute being rolled, which determines what dice/how many are rolled. I plan on eventually incorporating this into a Discord bot that will take the function and three arguments: the attribute, the attribute score and the level of advantage/disadvantage (which I haven't figured out yet).

I'll give this a shot! Thanks again!

Comment: Really hope it helps \o
Please, also consider accepting this answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Without recursion and with score system:

```
from random import randint as ri

score_mapping = {
    0 : None,
    1 : [(1, 4),],
    2 : [(1, 6),],
    3 : [(1, 8),],
    4 : [(1,10),],
    5 : [(1, 6), (1, 6)],
    6 : [(1, 8), (1, 8)],
    7 : [(1, 10), (1, 10)],
    8 : [(1, 8), (1, 8), (1, 8)],
    9 : [(1, 10), (1, 10), (1, 10)],
    10 : [(1, 8), (1, 10), (1, 10), (1, 10)],
}

def action_roll_script(score, roll_again_at=20):
    return_value = 0

    while True:

        value = ri(1, 20)

        print(f'score={score} rolled value={value}')

        if score == 0:
            return_value += value
        else:
            return_value += sum(ri(vf, vt) for (vf, vt) in score_mapping[score])

        if value != roll_again_at:
            break

    return return_value

print(action_roll_script(0))
```

Possible output:

```
score=10 rolled value=20
score=10 rolled value=5
38
```